# Open Source Flexviewer application

Tags: open-source-gis, flex, arcgis-flex-viewer

I would like to know if there are any open source flex viewers some thing on the same line as ArcGIS Flex Viewer  ??

Comment: for someone not knowing flex: what is so specific about is?

Comment: For working with ArcGIS Flex viewer you actually dont need to understand how Flex works in the back end.These Flex applications are pretty lightweight and with a pretty good user interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[OpenScales](http://openscales.org/) seems to be one and it appears to be endorsed by [WebMapSolutions](http://www.webmapsolutions.com/open-source-flex-gis-solutions).